# How to handle unbound variable without duplication?

Tags: bash

Consider the following common pattern to handle a command exit status:

```bash
if COMMAND; then
    echo success
else
    echo failure
fi
```

Using the same for variable assignment (given `set -o nounset`) doesn't work:

```
$ if foo="$no_such_variable"; then echo success; else echo failure; fi
bash: no_such_variable: unbound variable
```

A [variable substitution check](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) also doesn't work:

```
$ if foo="${no_such_variable:?}"; then echo success; else echo failure; fi
bash: no_such_variable: parameter null or not set
```

Is there some way to catch the return code of an assignment in an `if` statement? I'm trying to avoid the standard `if [[ $# -eq N ]]` workaround, because it couples that statement to each parameter assignment in the rest of the script rather than catching any issues at each assignment itself.

This is similar to the Python `if (foo := bar()):` pattern.

Comment: I thing you can use `${parameter:=word}` e.g. `if foo="${no_such_variable:=}" ; then...`

Comment: Btw the syntax `if foo="$no_such_variable"` isn't working for me properly. I always get (if the variable exists) `sucess`. I have to use `[ foo = "${no_such_variable:=}" ]`

Comment: I think you're performing the wrong kind of test.  If you want to test that a variable has a value in bash, use `if [[ -z ${variable_name} ]]` and then decide to perform the assignment or not.  Testing the success of an assignment statement (`foo="${variable_name}"`) does not test whether `$variable_name` had a value, but tests the shell's success in copying the value into `foo`, which isn't going to fail without the shell process being out of memory or another condition that's about to cause a catastrophic failure in the running process.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon `if foo="${no_such_variable:=}"; then echo success; else echo failure; fi` prints "success", which is not what I'm after. And `[ foo = "${no_such_variable:=}" ]` is not an assignment.

Comment: @l0b0 oh, I got it now!. I thought you wanted to compare two values :).

Answer (score 1):

You might try to build something around the built-in test for an unset variable: `test -v no_such_variable`. For example, a function `setvar` could do this test and only assign if it is ok:

```bash
set -o nounset
setvar(){
  declare -n var=$1 # -n is like ${!var} but for lvalue too
  declare value=$2
  [ -v ${value} ] && var="${!value}"
}
if setvar foo no_such_variable
then echo success
else echo failure
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to catch the return code of an assignment in an if statement?

I'm not sure there is a a useful exit status you could look at here.

What both a variable expansion under `set -u`/`nounset` and `${var?message}` do is *exit the shell* if the variable is unset. You can't look at any exit value in the script after that, since the script no longer runs.

If your assignment contained a command substitution, the exit status would come from there. Otherwise, an assignment just succeeds.

If you want to check if the variable is unset, you'll need to use the alternate value expansion, `${var+string}`, which expands to the given string if the variable is set (not using its value) and nothing if it's unset.

So

```
if [ "${var+set}" ]; then
    foo="$var"
    echo '$var copied to $foo'
else
    echo '$var is unset'
fi
```

or, you know, just disable `nounset` so that the copy doesn't fail:

```
set +u
foo="$var"
echo '$var copied to $foo'
```

Though if you need to check that there was a non-empty value, you'll need to do that separately.